# Problem $2.D.1$ from M.Isaacs book Finite Group Theory. Zenkov's theorem.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

Good afternoon. I am struggling with the second item of the followng problem.

> Let $G=NA$ be a finite group, where $N\vartriangleleft G, C_A(N)=1$ ($1$ is the identity element of $G$) and $A$ is abelian.
>
> (a) if $F(N)=1$, show that $|A|<|N|$.
>
> (b) if $|N|$ and $|A|$ coprime, show that $|A|<|N|$

Here $F(N)$ is a Fitting subgroup of $N$ that is the largest normal nilpotent subgroup of $N$. To solve this problem one may use the following fact.

> **Theorem (Consequence from Zenkov's Theorem)** Let $A\subseteq G$, where $A$ isabelian and $G$ is nontrivial finite group, assume that $|A|\geq|G:A|$. Then $|A\cap F(G)|>1.$

I give here my solution of the first item.

If $|A|\geq |N|$, then $|G:A|=|AN:A|=|N:A\cap N|\leq |N|\leq |A|$. So, by the mentioned theorem we obtain $|A\cap F(G)| >1$.

$F(G)\cap N\subseteq F(N)=1$, so $F(G)\subseteq C_G(N)$ and we obtain $1<F(G)\cap A\subseteq C_A(N)=1$. This is contradiction.

I am really stuck with the **second** item. We can assume that 
$$
|F(G)\cap N|>1
$$
(otherwise we arrive to the first item).
Also I have tried to choose an appropriate action by conjugation of some group $(A, F(G)\cap A,  F(N)...)$ on the other normal group $(F(G), N...)$ purposely to use the coprime condition. By my attempts fail.

Maybe a different approach will work? I will be grateful for the hints and ideas.

Comment: Summary of the approach, as described in the answer by User594801:

$N \cap A=1$ because the orders are coprime. Find a non-trivial $O_p(G)$ contained in $A$ then $N$ and $O_p(G)$ commute (they form a direct product) - this is a contradiction with $C_A(N) =1$.

To find this $O_p(G)$, notice that for any $p$ dividing $|A|$, we have $O_p(G) \subseteq A$, because $AN = G$ and $|A|$ and $|N|$ are coprime. Using $F(G) \cap A >1$, show that one of these $O_p(G)$ is non-trivial. This can be seen from the fact that $A \cap F(G) \subseteq \prod O_{p_i}(G)$, where $p_i$ divide $|A|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your solution to (a), you hit upon a strategy for all the problems in this section: look for normal subgroups of $G$ which have trivial intersection with $N$ (so centralize $N$) and nontrivial intersection with $A$, contradicting the assumption of a trivial centralizer of $N$ in $A$.

In (b), if $p$ is any prime dividing $|A \cap F(G)|>1$, then $O_p(G)$ is nontrivial normal. Since $p$ does not divide $|N|$ by the coprime condition, $O_p(G)$ has trivial intersection with $N$ and is contained in $A$ since it is contained in every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$, and Sylow $p$-subgroups of $A$ are Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ here.

Problem $2.D.2.$ can be solved with the same strategy using Theorem 2.20. of Lucchini.